# Is it possible to disable 'Print' and 'Export' buttons on Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, customization

I have Finished Designing my first Crystal Report using ASP.NET, I am Providing user my own way to Print and Export report, now i need to Hide or atleast disable the default Buttons provided in Crystal reports, Is it possible to do? how?

Comment: BTW, if you're going to continue developing reports you should take a look at MS SSRS controls. As to me they're better than CR.

Comment: i am using sql2005 express edition i dont think i can use sql reporting in that, can i?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class properties `ShowExportControls` and `ShowPrintButton`. There're more properties to disable standard viewer UI controls.

Comment: HOw is it related with Crystal Report Viewer?

Comment: The answer is about class ReprotViewer, not about application. Check the link from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an older version of Crystal Reports (such as 4.6 included in VB5/6) then this can be achieved in the following way:

- set the property "WindowControls=False" on the C.R. ActiveX control.

Doing so also disables the ability to Export and - as a side effect - also hides the buttons to zoom in/out of the report.

I'm leaving this comment for reference purposes only as - by now - everyone should be moving away from this VB/CR version.
Still, if like me, you are faced migrating or maintaining an older package this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

go to crystal reports viewer properties
and set these settings to false in VS 2015
HasExportButton="False" HasPrintButton="False"

Answer (score 0):

CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = false;

Answer (score 0):

CrystalReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = False

Answer (score -2):

using short cut key to take print out ,while you disable print button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).